# How to get and render points from a database firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-leaflet

So basically I was able to get a database which stores points in it.

Now I was able to push each point separately to make this database. Now I need to display these points on the map. This is my code so far:

App.js

```js
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMapEvents, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import CovidPoint from './CovidPoint';
import LocationMarkers from './LocationMarkers';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      map: null,
      points: [<CovidPoint
      position={[43.653226, -79.3831843]}
      name="point1"
      information="random point"
      input = {false}
    ></CovidPoint>]
    }
  }

  changePos = (pos, zoom) => {
    const {map} = this.state;
    if (map) map.flyTo(pos, zoom);
  }

  fetchPoints = (newPoints) => {
    // fetch info from database
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("points")
    const pointsref = ref.push()
    pointsref.set(newPoints)
    this.setState({points: newPoints})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("points")
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      console.log("FireB ",snapshot)
      if (snapshot && snapshot.exists()) {
        this.setState({points: snapshot.val})
      }})
    console.log("page loaded!")
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="title">
          <h1>CovidStopSpots</h1>
          <p>A responsive tracker for Covid-19.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
          <MapContainer
            id="1"
            center={[43.653226, -79.3831843]}
            zoom={13}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            whenCreated={(map) => this.setState({ map })}
            style={{ height: "100vh " }}
          >
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {this.state.points.length > 0 && this.state.points.map(
      (point, index) => {
        <li key={index}></li>
        return point
      }) }
            {/* <CovidPoint
              position={[43.653226, -79.3831843]}
              name="point1"
              information="random point"
            ></CovidPoint>
            <CovidPoint
              position={[50.653226, -79.3831843]}
              name="point2"
              information="random point"
            ></CovidPoint> */}
            <LocationMarkers points={this.state.points} fetchPoints={this.fetchPoints}></LocationMarkers>
            <div id="searchbar">
            <SearchBar changePos={this.changePos}/>
            </div>
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The location Marker file which basically "plots" the points and pushes the to the database.

LocationMarker.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import CovidPoint from "./CovidPoint";

function LocationMarkers(props) {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([]);
  useMapEvents({
    dblclick(ev) {
      console.log("double clicked");
      const { lat, lng } = ev.latlng;
      setPosition([lat, lng]);
      const newPoints = [...props.points];
      console.log(newPoints);
      newPoints.push(<CovidPoint
        position={[lat, lng]}
        name="test"
        information="test"
        input = {true}
      ></CovidPoint>);
      props.fetchPoints(newPoints);
    }
  });

  return null;

}

export default LocationMarkers;
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your map component?

Comment: sure, I'm so done with this an so confused that ill just share all my code. The error that im getting right now is TypeError: props.points is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on [this example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker) from documentation, you should use Marker to place a marker. Assuming that you have an array of points (list of coordinates), you can place a list of points like this:

```
const position = [
  [51.505, -0.09],
  [51.510, -0.09],
  [51.515, -0.09]
]

render(
  <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    {points?.map((point)=>(
      <Marker position={point}>
    )}
    </Marker>
  </MapContainer>,
)
```

I don't know what is this CovidPoint. But I think you dont need it.

Comment: My code is already working with the way I have it set up. And covid point is the class that is making the actual points (markers). I just need to know how to load the data from the database when i start the page. Also a weird error I'm getting is that points is not iterable, is there a way to fix that without changing my structure?